# WPF WebBrowser opens Adobe Reader 10 instead of displaying the pdf inside the browser

Tags: c#, wpf, pdf, adobe

I'm facing a quite difficult problem. I inherited a software framework (roughly 100k lines of code) and now I want to display PDF files within this software. Since I can put WPF UserControls into this, I created a light-weight UC containing a WPF WebBrowser. I then used the Navigate() method to load a PDF document. Unfortunately, the WebBrowser does not display the PDF document, but instead opens up Adobe Reader 10 in a separate window/process. It will display HTML just fine, but even embedding the PDF inside HTML (using the <object>-tag or <iframe> did not display the pdf though, but caused Adobe Reader to open). When I use the same code in a standalone app (with no code from the framework), the WebBrowser displays the PDF as expected. 
Modifying the Registry to allow feature emulation did not solve this issue either.

I've been looking for a solution for days now and cannot seem to find anything. So here is were I hope to get some insight:

How do I get my standalone app to behave like my framework? I did not seem to find anything about this either, but I hope that by managing this, I'll be able to fix the issue with my framework.

Comment: What's your default browser and how does it handle PDFs ?

Comment: Default browser is Internet Explorer 11.0.9600. The browser displays PDF files embedded using Adobe Reader

Answer (score 1):

Okay, I kinda feel dumb for not paying attention to this:

My test app works because its being compiled in x86, while my Framework uses x64. Apparently, the WPF WebBrowser (same's true for the WinForms WebBrowser Control) are not able to render PDFs when they are running in an x64 app. Once it changed the target platform in my test app from x86 to x64, it also began opening up Adobe Reader...